# Changing the UI of Dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdownbox

How to make the Image Button as Drop-down list. If i click a Image Button the Drop-down list should come .[image]

If I click that funnel image.The Drop-down will be appeared

Comment: Did you see some of the code available on Internet.. http://www.studyoverflow.org/2013/05/simple-dropdown-button-using-jquery-in.html Now apply style as per your need and you are done!!

Comment: I think it is the simplest solution you just need to alter style sheet